# How to use toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table border=2>
    <tr>
        <td class="here" one="lorem" two="ipsum"> click </td>
        <td class="here" one="aaa" two="bbb"> click </td>
    </tr>
</table>

$('.here').click(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).attr('one'));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uzhru/

How can i modify this javascript for function toggle or other solution?
I would like - if i click on TD then this show me attribute one, and if i next click then this show me attribute two, next one, next two etc

Comment: Note that custom attributes like `one` and `two` will stop your code validating correctly. If you are using HTML5 you should use `data-*` attributes instead.

Comment: If you're using custom attributes, you should really be using HTML5 `data-*` attributes, then using the jQuery `.data()` function to get/set their values.

Comment: thanks, but this working on all browsers? and where i can find good tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ocanal's answer works perfectly but I thought I'd add that this can also be done with `toggle` which when given two functions will switch between them for each click:

```
$(".here").toggle(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).attr('one'));
}, function() {
    $(this).html($(this).attr('two'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7pUS4/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.here').click(function(){
  if($(this).html() == $(this).attr('one'))
    $(this).html($(this).attr('two'));
  else 
    $(this).html($(this).attr('one'));
})​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nps8B/1)